# Is it possible to use Jupyter Notebook for AWS Glue instead of Zeppelin

Tags: python, jupyter, aws-glue

I got started using AWS Glue for my data ETL. I've pulled in my data sources into my AWS data catalog, and am about to create a job for the data from one particular Postgres database I have for testing. I have read online that when authoring your own job, you can use a Zeppelin notebook. I haven't used Zeppelin at all, but have used Jupyter notebook heavily as I'm a python developer, and was using it a lot for data analytics, and machine learning self learnings. I haven't been able to find it anywhere online, so my question is this **"Is there a way to use Jupyter notebook in place of a Zeppelin notebook when authoring your own AWS Glue jobs?"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be possible, if you can setup a Jupyter notebook locally, and enable SSH tunneling to the AWS Glue.  I do see some reference sites for setting up local Jupyter notebook, enable SSH tunneling, etc, though not AWS Glue specific.

Comment: Thanks Yuva, is it possible that you could include some of those links? I was having a hard time finding them.

Comment: For Jupyter notebook, I came across this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-jupyter-notebook-to-run-ipython-on-ubuntu-16-04  and for Zeppelin, https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/apache-zeppelin-installation-on-windows-10/

Comment: Also for SSH tunneling, I think you can use GitBash, and use the ssh url provided at AWS Glue while creating a Dev Endpoint.

Comment: you may also try this link to setup pyspark/jupyter on windows: http://www.jbencina.com/blog/2017/07/15/installing-pyspark-jupyter-notebook-windows/, though I have not tried this.  I have setup zeppelin on windows and using as dev endpoint when needed for AWS glue

Comment: Why is there a down vote? Think I have helped with the links requested for.  Can you clarify. Thx

Comment: :) Thanks. no issues.

Answer (score 0):

As of July 2021, Glue supports two kinds of notebooks

- Sagemaker notebooks (which is backed by Jupyter)
- Zeppelin notebooks.

Documentation [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-notebooks.html)